# I want to travel to Canada on a valid B1 (Business visitor)

Tags: visas, canada, international-travel

I have a B1 Business visitor visa for Canada and I visited Canada on this visa for my company's business. Now I want to visit Canada. Can I travel for tourism on this business visitor visa?